# How do I determine if an entity has been saved?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Using Code-first EF 4. If I have an object, how can I determine in a general way if it has been saved previously (without querying the DB).  A newly instantiated object has an EntityState of Unchanged. So does an object retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 0):

If any entity has a auto generated id, then the id will only be generated when the entity is saved.

So you can check if the id is 0.

**Edit**

I agree with the comments. But if you design your database with autoids, this works. There has been no other answers on SO for 2 months so chances are there may not be another way.

Also, if you go to the database to check if it is a new record or not, how will you test that it is a new record or not at the database level?

Comment: Not necessarily - Id isn't a readonly property on your class, it could be set by anything

Comment: In addition to what RichardW1001 said, this is not a **general** way to determine this.